# Cascading Dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am using many dropdownlists on my page,and i am migrating my project from .net 2003 to .net 2008.I want to  Ajaxify my page and is it logical to use cascading dropdownlists?Can Cascading Dropdownlist  give any unexpected problem?By the way,if i use Cascading Dropdownlist,i use pagemethods,not webservices?Do Pagemethods give  any problems?Or Do u have advice instead of Cascading Dropdownlist?I dont want to use 3.party components annd thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that I can say against Cascading dropdownlists is that they can be harder to debug if something goes wrong with the WebMethod they are calling, as they will only return cryptic error messages.  However, once you realize that that's what's happening, it's a pretty quick step to fix it.

Otherwise, they work great, and save a whack of plumbing code to enable/disable.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with the ASP.NET AJAX Toolkit. It works. If you're not using the same dropdowns on another page then use a pagemethod they're much easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "LoginForm", autocomplete = "off" }))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score -2):

```
routes:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace PrivateExchange
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "MediaResourcePopup",
                url: "Home/MediaResourcePopup/{wid}/{uiconf_id}/{cache_st}/{entry_id}/{targetId}",
                defaults: new
                {
                    controller = "Home",
                    action = "MediaResourcePopup"
                });

            //routes.MapRoute(
            //name: "BridgeFront",
            //url: "{BridgeFront}/{LaunchBridgeFront}/{user}",
            //defaults: new { controller = "BridgeFront", action = "LaunchBridgeFront", user = "keenan" }
            //);


            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Message",
               url: "Message/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Message", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Plan",
                url: "Plan/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Plan", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Enrollment",
                url: "Enrollment/{action}/{id}/{memberCodes}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Enrollment", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, memberCodes = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "UserManagement",
                url: "UserManagement/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "UserManagement", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Employee",
                url: "Employee/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Employee", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Dependent",
                url: "Dependent/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Dependent", action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "DecisionSupport",
                url: "DecisionSupport/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "DecisionSupport", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Package",
                url: "Package/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Package", action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Home",
                url: "Home/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional,type=UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "KCaresHome",
               url: "Home/{action}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Login", type = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Root",
                url: "{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name : "SSO",
                url : "SSO/SSO/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "SSO", action = "SSO" }
                );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Upload",
                url: "Upload/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Upload", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

 1. List item

enter code here
        }

}
```

Comment: Please describe your answer. Currently it is unclear which part of the question(s) this answers.